# Is prayer obligated in Christianity, and if so how many times a day?

Tags: prayer

Is prayer **obligated** in Christianity (as it's in Judaism and Islam), and if so **how many times a day**?

I've heard so many different pieces of information and I'm confused about it.

Comment: "Obligation" isn't a term that fits Christianity particularly well, however a prayerless Christian is an indication that something is very wrong. You can't be relying on God without living out your reliance on God.

Comment: I found this guy is saying something about 3 times a day that was in past, based on 'acts of apostles'. I didn't understand where it's exactly in this book to check. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsYFIKzkCpc

Comment: Jesus said 'When ye pray, say Our Father which art in heaven . . . and so on. He did not specify how long, or how often. It is voluntary. There are _examples_ in scripture which one may wish to follow, such as in the psalms and in Daniel, where three times a day is spoken of.

Answer (score 2):

There is no common rule to Christians.
Most monastic traditions know frequent fixed prayer times. They are not fixed by any OT or NT scripture but on the rules of the order or the monastery or convent. Commonly, there are the Laudes in the morning, several hour prayers during the daytime, the Vesper in the evening and the Complet in the night.

Protestants usually pray before the meals (morning, lunch, dinner) and in the sunday service. They may pray at any time they want. There is no fixed obligation for prayer for laic Christians.

Answer (score 0):

1 Thessalonians 5:17 gives the answer.

> "Rejoice at all times. Pray without ceasing. Give thanks in every
> circumstance, for this is God’s will for you in Christ Jesus." (Berean
> Study Bible)

You are enjoined to pray without ceasing.

Q: Does this mean I should be constantly repeating words of prayer, either out loud or subvocally?

A: No, that is not what is meant. It means one ought to be continually seeking out and communing with God in one's heart. This is the essence of prayer, and one is enjoined to cultivate that attitude of the heart without ceasing.

Comment: I found this guy is saying something about 3 times a day that was in past, based on 'acts of apostles'. I didn't understand where it's exactly in this book to check. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsYFIKzkCpc

Comment: We are enjoined to be thankful, to be joyful and to be in a spirit of prayer, continually. That is to say, not to be found at a distance from the Lord, in our heart. It does _not_ mean, as I have heard and read some imply, that one is always _mentally_ making prayers in one's head. Some imply that as though that is what they do, without actually making the claim.

Comment: @NigelJ "It does not mean, as I have heard and read some imply, that one is always mentally making prayers in one's head." This is a good clarification - if someone means subvocally repeating words in prayer continually, no, it doesn't mean that.

Answer (score 0):

#### No.

Although we are *encouraged* to pray frequently, even "without ceasing" (1 Thessalonians 5:17) as noted in another answer, a *requirement* to pray would be a form of works righteousness, which is explicitly condemned, especially by Paul (e.g. Ephesians 2:8-9).

As far as I know, no Protestant/Reformed denominations *require* prayer.

That said, Catholics reject [Sola Gratia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sola_gratia) and impose various requirements on parishioners as "penance", which I believe may include saying prayers, though as I understand this usually takes the form of "you did X; as penance, say the Lord's Prayer Y times" and not a requirement to pray a specific number of times *per day*.

I don't know about Orthodox...

Comment: not all penances in Catholicism are explicitly prayers of any form; and depending on how one understands "required", that may not be the only form of prayer "required"

Comment: @eques, I'm aware there are other forms of penance; that's why I said "*may include* saying prayers". To your second point, I would guess that "required" is something like "must do or there will be spiritual conseqeuences", but that would be for the OP to clarify.

Comment: "required" can mean either something like a codified expectation or required in the sense of without doing so, some negative outcome will result. e.g Catholicism says that prayer develops intimacy with God and grow in virtue, so in that sense it is relatively necessary